# VueJS - How to refresh data in a component from another component?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vuejs2

I am trying to refresh a component from another component but I get the following error: `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'top')`

Component #1: Here is the table

```js
data(){
  names: []
},
methods: {
   async getData(currPage) 
        {
            console.log('testing data');
            const skip = (currPage - 1) * this.page.top;
            const response = await this.axios.get(`/s/names`, {
                params: {
                    skip: skip,
                    top: this.page.top,
                },
            } );
            this.page = response.data.pages;
            
            this.names = response.data.data;
        },
          refreshPage()
        {
            console.log('testing');
            return this.getData() ;
        },

}
```

```html
<template>
     <tr v-for="name in names" :key="name.id">
           <td>{{ name }}</td>
           
      </tr>
</template>
```

Component #2: And here is the refresh button:

```js
methods: {
   refreshAction()
        {
            
            switch (this.$route.name) {         
                case "nameseadmin":
                    return namesAdmin.methods.refreshPage();
            }
            return null;
        
        },
         refreshPage()
        {
            if (!this.refreshAction) return;
            if(typeof this.refreshAction === "function")      this.refreshAction();
            else this.$store.dispatch(this.refreshAction);
        },

}
```

```html
<template>
 <refresh-button
          id="refresh-button"
          :class="refresh-style"
          @on-refresh="refreshPage"
        />
</template>
```

I know the function in my #1 component is being called because I see the console.log('testing') being fired but the table isn't refreshing. What am I doing wrong or what is the correct way to refresh the table? Any advice is appreciated!

Comment: The error indicates that it cannot find `this.page`. Where is it defined? Please provide more details and a whole code snippet of the relevant file.

Comment: https://blog.logrocket.com/using-event-bus-in-vue-js-to-pass-data-between-components/

Comment: @ВикторКарев no, don't use an event bus.

Comment: I was able to fix this error but now I'm getting the following error: Uncaught (in promise) `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'get') `
new getDatamethod:
`{ console.log('testing data');
const skip = (currPage - 1) * this.page;
const response = await this.axios.get(`/s/names`, {
params: {
skip: skip,
top: this.page,
 },
} );
this.page = response.data.pages;
this.names = response.data.data;
},` I removed top